# JMETER WILL MEASURE TIME file processing time?

Tags: jmeter

My application has few modules register customer,account and wallet etc..  Currently we are using JMETER to collect the  response time for the server.

Now we are introducing adding customer by batch process (dropping files in to server) so that customer will be added and customer gets the URL link to download the app.  I wanted to measure how long server takes to create all the customers in the file..

Can any one suggest how to measure for this approach? I guess the difference between first record created time and last record created time in db is the process time that I am calculating.. any other good approach is there??

Comment: I hope you are using FTP to process the batch jobs. If yes, you can create FTP samplers in your test plan. To get the response time for each record, you can use your database as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks. This tip helps me.

Comment: Can i put this in the answer? Will you accept it?

Comment: Sure. I will accept

Comment: It is done. Please check.

Comment: Accepted.. thanks for the link FTP test plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using FTP to process each customer records, you can leverage **FTP Samplers** in JMeter. Check this link on [how to create FTP plan in JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ftp-test-plan.html).

Another best resource is from [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter).

To get the response time for each customer, you can follow the same process as you mentioned in the question.